# Is uniform continuous send bouded sequence to a bounded sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let  $f\colon\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $\displaystyle \sup_{x\in \mathbb R}|f'(x)|<\infty$. Then which are correct?

(A) $f$ maps bounded sequence to a bounded sequence.

(B) $f$ maps Cauchy sequence to a Cauchy sequence.

(C) $f$ maps convergent sequence to a convergent sequence.

(D) $f$ is uniformly continuous.

**Attempt :**

Since $\displaystyle \sup_{x\in \mathbb R}|f'(x)|<\infty$ so $f$ is uniformly continuous. (D),(B).

As $\mathbb R$ is complete and (B) is TRUE so (C) is also TRUE.

But I am unable to prove or disprove the option (A).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that if you let $M = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f'(x)|$ then by the mean value theorem, you have

$$ |f(x) - f(y)| \leq M|x - y| $$

for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. If $\{ x_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a bounded sequence, then there exists $C$ such that $|x_n| \leq C$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Using the estimate above, we have

$$ ||f(x_n)| - |f(0)|| \leq |f(x_n) - f(0)| \leq M|x_n - 0| \leq MC $$

so $|f(x_n)| \leq MC + |f(0)|$ which implies that $\{ f(x_n) \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded.