# Which of the following options are true in case of a differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be  a differentiable function such that $\sup _{x\in \Bbb R} |f^{'}(x)|<\infty$. Then which are true:

1. $f$ maps bounded sequences to bounded sequences.
2. $f$ maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.
3. $f$ maps convergent  sequences to convergent
4. $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Let $|f^{'}(x)|\leq M$ for some $M>0$ .Then $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\leq |f^{'}(x) ||x_1-x_2|\leq M(x_1-x_2)<\epsilon $ whenever $|x_1-x_2|<\delta $.Thus $f$ is uniformly continuous.So $2,3,4$ are true.

But how to prove /disprove $1$?

Comment: And http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585211/is-uniform-continuous-send-bouded-sequence-to-a-bounded-sequence/1585217#1585217

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a sequence is bounded, the values are in some interval $(a,b)$. Hence the values of $f(x)$ on it are in $(Ma,Mb)$, where $M$ is the constant from your solution for the other cases.